# What is the best way to share links between models?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I need to make a bunch of models each having an identical copy of a particular link. What's the best way of doing that without copying and pasting the entire XML for the link every time? Can I use an <include> element for this somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14257/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-links-between-models?/) by [JasonMel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2774/jasonmel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've never tried this, but it should be possible to `<include>` a model within another one. The SDF parser just expands the links of the included model within the parent model. You can see an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/c9ba518c76bbb7943a9106609f6106a11331c4cb/iris_with_standoffs_demo/model.sdf?at=aero_testing_john&fileviewer=file-view-default).

So in your case, you could make a base model which has the link that should be shared, and include that in each new model.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JasonMel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2774/jasonmel/) on 2016-09-19**:
This definitely works. Thanks!